# ControllerMixin `actions` object isn't recognized in `send`

Tags: ember.js

Not sure if this is a bug or intended behavior. I've created an Ember.Object that includes the ControllerMixin. This gives it the `send` function, which should be able to find functions within the `actions` object. It cannot do so, however. Instead, it looks in the private `_actions` object, so that if I put my actions inside of `_actions`, everything works. Is this intended? If so, why?

Code sample:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const { Component, on } = Ember;

export default Component.extend({

  triggerFoo: on('init', function() {
    const bar = this.get('bar');
    bar.send('foo');
  })

});
```

...

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const { ControllerMixin } = Ember;

export default Ember.Object.extend(ControllerMixin, {

  _actions: {

    foo() {
      console.log('`foo` was triggered');
    }

  }
});
```

Comment: could you please post the code ?

Comment: @engma updated with code sample.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an explanation here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/9459

TL;DR it has backward compatibility issues with the days when actions was not special property and you could use actions to be anything. It can be fixed in Ember 2.0.